# Trouble with constructor: Natural Number using Stack<Integer>

Tags: java, constructor, initialization, stack, nullpointerexception

I'm trying to create an arbitrarily long natural number using a stack of integers. I'm pretty new to Java, but here's what I've got so far:

```
import java.util.Stack;

public class BigNatural {      // I didn't choose that name >.>

private Stack< Integer > number;

public BigNatural(String value_in) {

while(value_in.length() > 0) {

char temp_char = value_in.charAt(0);

Integer temp_int = Character.digit(temp_char, 10);

this.number.push(temp_int);

if(value_in.length() > 1) {
value_in = value_in.substring(1); }

else { break; }
}
}
```

I'm getting a `NullPointerException` on the line with `this.number.push`. Is there something I'm not doing in terms of initializing the Stack correctly? Adding `number = new Stack< Integer >();` allowed my initialize test to run, but I feel like that only creates a local Stack that goes out of scope. Help!

Edit: (see comments below)

```
public void increment () {
  Integer temp_int = 0;

  if(!this.number.empty()) {

    temp_int = this.number.pop();
    temp_int++;

    if(temp_int == 10) {
      this.increment();
      this.number.push(0);
    } else { 
      this.number.push(temp_int); 
    }    
  } else { 
    this.number.push(1);
  }
}
```

Thanks again in advance for any help!

Comment: Well obviously this is supposed to be my constructor for the class if the argument is a string. I can't just toss a return statement at the end since it's a non-primitive type can I?

Comment: If this is homework, could you please tag it as such?

Comment: It's part of a larger project, but it is academic in nature, so it could probably be tagged as homework. Which tag should be taken off is the real question o.O

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will not go out of scope because you assign the newly created `Stack` to the class variable `number`.

Furthermore, the `NullPointerException` is thrown because `number` is not initialized.

You need to initialize `number` before the `while` loop, or you can change this line:

```
private Stack<Integer> number;
```

to

```
private Stack<Integer> number = new Stack<Integer>();
```

Comment: Gold Star for ryanprayogo. Removing all the new lines from each constructor and making your change actually cleared up all the NullPointerExceptions. Again, new to java. I appreciate the quick responses from everyone!

Answer (score 3):

> Adding `number = new Stack< Integer >();` allowed my initialize test to run, but I feel like that only creates a local Stack that goes out of scope.

It won't be going "out of scope", because you're saving it in the class member `number`.

Comment: I have a method for the class that is supposed to increment my number by 1. There's an if statement to check !this.number.empty() before popping off the last digit, adding one, and pushing it back on. That's returning a NullPointerException too, but I'm pretty sure I can't call new this time. Why aren't the values of my stack saved?